# Using Raycaster to change the colour of a Box's face when clicked

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I have tried to get the raycaster to be able to select one of the cubes faces that  have been created and to then change the face's colour that has been clicked on. I have been able to get it working with a whole object but not the objects individual faces.

Could someone please explain the difference between intersectObject() and intersectObjects() as I think that this is involved in the issue.

Here is the code of the attempt on selecting a face of the cube, which loads but does not do anything when a cube's face is clicked

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ){ 
    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( mesh );

    for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++){
        intersects[ i ].face.color.setHex( 0xDDC2A3 );
        mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdating = true;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
   }
```

}

And here is on of the cubes in my scene

```
var cubeGeometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
var cubeMaterial2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffff00});
var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry2, cubeMaterial2);
//Cube position to sit on top of the plane, allow to cast shadows and add
cube2.position.x = -5;
cube2.position.y = -5;
cube2.position.z = -5;
scene.add(cube2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could someone please explain the difference between intersectObject() and intersectObjects() as I think that this is involved in the issue.

Like mentioned in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster) of `THREE.Raycaster`, `intersectObject()` expects a single object whereas `intersectObjects()` expects an array of objects as first parameter. However, it has nothing to do with your issue.

The problem is the way how you setup your material. If you want to have a color for each face, you have to set `THREE.Material.vertexColors` to `THREE.FaceColor`. Keep in mind that this approach does only work with `THREE.Geometry`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sv05rwny/

`three.js R101`